# Can't add web service project to solution in Visual Studios 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a web service that Visual Studio just won't let me add to my solution.

- If I right click on the solution, click Add, then Existing Project, then I navigate to my project, select the Visual C# Project file, I get "The local IIS URL http://127.0.0.1:8099/ specified for web project has not been configured.
- It asks if I would like to create the virtual directory now.

  - If I choose no, nothing happens
  - If I choose yes, creation failed error, could not find the server http://127.0.0.1:8099 on the local machine.
- Creating a virtual directory is only supported on the local IIS server.

Does anybody know how to fix this?  I've been struggling with it for a while.  Thanks

Comment: Ok, I finally fixed this and I wanted to post my fix just in case anybody comes across a similar situation.  I just installed SP1 for Visual Studios 2010 and that fixed the issue.  That issue had been a real pain for a long time.